# ASP.NET MVC - JQuery -Validate unique values for an editable table column

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have using ASP.NET MVC razor and JQuery. I have the following model.

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]        
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
```

I render this as a table. The number field is editable input field. Rows can be added and removed from the table. When a row is added the number field is empty and can be assigned a number.

```
@model List<Models.Employee> 

 <thead>....
 </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                 <td>...
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Number, new { @id ="", @title = "Number", @class = "textBox", @autocomplete = "false"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].Number)
                </td>                   
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
```

I want to validate before I do a save if all the numbers in the Number column are unique. I'm using JQuery unobtrusive validation. I don't see a [Unique] DataAnnotation in MVC? I want to know what is the best way to validate if all the number fields in my table are unique and how to tie it to form validation i.e. form validation should fail if there are non-unique values. And all I need is just client side validation.

Comment: you can check it by remote validation http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/check-instantly-if-username-exists-asp-net-mvc-remote-validation

Comment: sorry, all the employees are on the table in the view. There is nothing on the server side that I have check. I just need client side validation.

Comment: you want to check the number is unique in database or not, right?

Comment: try handling the form.submit event and checking the values yourself using javascript.. you dont need unobtrusive validation for this

Comment: And you should still check server side as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built validation attributes that will handle this. One way would be to handle the forms `.submit()` event and cancel the event if the values are not unique. Give each textbox for the property a class name (say) `class="number"` and include an element in your view for displaying an error message

```
<div id="uniqueerror" class="field-validation-error"></div>
```

and add the following script

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var numbers = [];
  // add the textbox values to the array
  $.each($('.number'), function () {
    numbers .push($(this).val());
  });
  // create a new array containing only unique values
  var unique = numbers.filter(function (item, index, numbers) {
    return index == arr.indexOf(item);
  });
  // compare them
  if (numbers.length !== unique.length) {
    // display error message and cancel the submit
    $('#uniqueerror').text('The numbers must be unique');
    return false;
  }
});
```

You could also handle the textbox `.change()` event to clear the error message.

Side note: You should always validate on the server as well. Client side validation is a nice bonus and improves the user experience but can be easily bypassed. The server side validation could be

```
var numbers = model.Select(m => m.Number);
if (numbers.Count() != numbers.Distinct().Count())
{
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "The numbers must be unique");
}
```